# Where to look in D7 if virtual tabs in cck edit form do not appear?

Tags: entities, routes

I'm having some problem with my D7 installation - I've migrated from D6 on this. Thing is, when I create content of a CCK type, some of the vertical tabs on the bottom of the form are not available for some types, but not for all.

I cannot find the settings where and how to change this behavior. I'm missing the 'menu settings', 'revision information', 'authoring information' and 'comment settings'. Didn't find an option in the cck settings or variables.

Since the system does not report any error on this, it's hard to find in what database table the settings are hiding and what goes wrong.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Are you seeing these fields missing on the master admin account? If not, could be a permissions problem. Look in People > Permissions. If it is on the master account, make sure your selected modules are enabled (e.g. meta tag module for meta tags vertical node tabs.)

Comment: Yep, when logged in as main admin. I.e. I don't think it's about permissions.

Comment: The page array contents (devel) do list all settings tabs under content/system_main/additional_settings/group/#groups/additional_settings
Difference to a working content type is under this path, the #access is set to false. So d'you have an idea where this #access-value is configured in?

Comment: Virtual tabs? Don't you mean vertical ones?

Comment: jeez, of course. stupid me!